# How to make a macro expand before stringifying it in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I'm trying to write a quine in Rust using only macros.
In order to do that, I'm embedding the `main` function into macro `f1`, and trying to embed a literal representation of `f1` in `f2` with `stringify!`.

Here is my code so far:

```
macro_rules!f1{()=>(fn main(){println!("macro_rules!{}\nmacro_rules!f2{{($x:expr)=>(stringify!($x))}}\nf1!();",f2!(f1));})}
macro_rules!f2{($x:expr)=>(stringify!($x))}
f1!();
```

The output is, unsurprisingly:

```
macro_rules!f1
macro_rules!f2{($x:expr)=>(stringify!($x))}
f1!();
```

What I need is for `f1` to expand before being stringified in order for the program to be quine. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't control the order of expansion. IIRC, somebody once suggested a syntax based on how many `!` you used, i.e. `!!x` gets resolved before `!f2`, but this idea did not find much support. I like your idea of a macro-based quine btw :)

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate! I managed to do it but without stringify!, so it's pretty unreadable unfortunately.

Comment: @JonNimrod Please would you care to provide your workaround solution for this issue is documented and can be useful for others in the same situation?